# Using *value in multiple classes

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am sure this is horribly simple but it had had be perplexed for hours.

Say I have the following setup below: (simplified)

```
-(void) ClassA {
CCSprite *boat = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"boat.png"];
[self addChild: boat];
}

-(void) ClassB {
CGPoint velocity = CGPointMake(0, 1);
boat.position = ccpAdd(boat.position, velocity);
}
```

How would I make the *boat for ClassA usable in ClassB?

Comment: Are `ClassA` & `ClassB` two methods belonging to the same class, or is their naming meant to imply they are methods distinct classes?

Answer (score 3):

Make it member variable of `ClassA` and write getter method for `CCSprite *boat`.

```
+(CCSprite *)boat
{
return boat;
}
```

Now in class B

```
[ClassA boat];
```

**EDIT**
You could also use properties or associated objects... both work exceptionally well as suggested by [Richard J. Ross III](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii).
If you require only a single instance of an object in your application,Take a look at [Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) post.

Comment: You could also use properties or associated objects... both work exceptionally well.